# Unable to view some fonts properly in Debian 8.2

Tags: linux, debian, fonts

[image]

I am using Debian 8.2 on my intel core2duo,4 Gib ram but having problem in viewing some of the fonts as shown below.

I am facing this problem only with Debian. I have tried Fedora, Mint, and Ubuntu and all of them work fine. My chipset is Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset.

Answer (score 1):

You could try going to `about:config` and try out changing various graphical-related settings there, e.g.:

- `layers.offmainthreadcomposition.enabled`
- `layers.acceleration.disabled`
- `layers.offmainthreadcomposition.force-basic`

Comment: I tried some combinations of settings and that didn't seem to improve my situation.One more thing this issue is not only in iceweasel but in chrome also.

Comment: It certainly looks like a problem with GPU accelerated drawing, I know these even from Windows. Try to tinker with your GPU driver and its settings.

Comment: Thank you ,I am facing this problem only with debian.I have tried Fedore,Mint,Ubuntu all of them works fine.My chipset is Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset ,I am a beginner so please elaborate how to tinker with my GPU?

Comment: Ah OK, you should've included that info in the original post then.